# Change aspect ratio in beamer for a single frame?

Tags: beamer

I have a presentation in 4:3, but would like to include a single slide from a 16:9 presentation made in beamer.  These are complex slides, with subtle layout and animation, so I would prefer not to adapt the slide to 4:3. It is easier for me to admit that one slide will have a different aspect ratio.  I was however not able to find any suggestions online, how to change aspectratio for a single frame.

This is one of the things I would like to understand in beamer, to increase my quest in making my beamer presentations more reusable.  In Power Point it is relatively easy to glue presentations from existing fragments of other ones.

Comment: Make an individual document for the 16:9 slide and include this via `pdfpages` in between your frames.

Comment: Yes, this might work, but it is rather tedious for a slide that translates to 30 frames due to animation. Is there really no way to change paper size for one frame?

Comment: pdfpages can import a range of pages at once

Comment: and it is the other way round: a frame translates into multiple slides :)

Comment: good point. I guess this might be my best bet so far. Will do for what I need to do today, as I don't need, luckily, to make any adjustments to colors, etc.

Comment: Tested @samcarter's idea.  I can only make it to work with empty background color, and the page size still remains 4:3, the included pdf pages are centered on my presentation pages, so the slide has ugly white space above and below the content.  Using pdftk  would give a better outcome, but is more annoying.   I would still hope that one can change papersize for one page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not difficult to change the page width if you don't care about layout elements like navigation symbols:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}


\setlength\pdfpagewidth{16.00cm}%
\setlength\pdfpageheight{9.00cm}%

\begin{frame}
blub
\pause
blub
\pause 

blub
\end{frame}

\setlength\pdfpagewidth{12.80cm}%
\setlength\pdfpageheight{9.60cm}%


\begin{frame}
blub
\pause

blub
\pause

blub
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Exactly what I needed! Works like a charm. Correct slide numbers and all. So cool.